# how to stop a function from running if its already been run

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio

I have a DataGrid with columns Qty, Reason and Comment. The user can edit these fields, and when they do, a debrief is created. But I only want the debrief to be created once - the first time something is updated. If the debrief is already created then I don't want to create it again. So for example the user edits the comment textbox then this code is run:

```
public static void UpdateSerialComment(int SerNoID, string Comment)
    {
        JobPieceSerialNo SerNo = new JobPieceSerialNo(SerNoID);
        SerNo.Comment = Comment;
        SerNo.DeliveryDate = DateTime.Now;
        SerNo.DeliveryUser = CurrentUser.Username;
        SerNo.Update();

        UpdateDebrief(ID, ItemNo, QtyDelivered, QtyNOTDelivered, Reason);

    }
```

I have similar functions for the other fields when they get updated. So when this function is run it calls the UpdateDebrief function:

```
 public static void UpdateDebrief(int ID, string ItemNo, int QtyDelivered, int QtyNOTDelivered, string Reason)
    {
            JobDebrief deb = new JobDebrief
            {
                JobID = ID,
                ItemNo = "",
                QtyDelivered = 0,
                QtyNotDelivered = 0,
                DbriefReason = "",
                DbriefDate = DateTime.Now,
                DbriefedBy = CurrentUser.UserID
            };
            deb.Create();
    }
```

This creates a new row in the database. How do I check if the UpdateDebrief function has been run? And if it has been run already then don't run again?

Comment: how about you add global variable

Comment: @kyle I tried creating a bool but that causes this error: `Error 2411 An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property 'JobDeliveryDebrief.DbriefCreated' `

Comment: maintain a static flag and add a condition to block requests.

Comment: @SufyanJamil could you show some code on how to do this?

Comment: @SufyanJamil This question is marked as ASP.NET.  A static flag or global flag is completely the wrong answer.   That completely breaks if you have multiple users or if the website is restarted.

Comment: add global variable public static bool flag = false; if( flag == false ) {UpdateDebrief(ID, ItemNo, QtyDelivered, QtyNOTDelivered, Reason); flag = true;}

Comment: @shf301 , yes you are right. thanks for correction. than i you can block the button on webform just after the click so user cant click again.

Comment: Why not create some type of singleton class for `JobDebrief` so you don't have to worry about `UpdateDebrief` being called multiple times, since it won't create another `JobDebrief`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure exactly what you are doing here, but if this debrief object is one object for the entire grid, you could store it in a session variabe.  For example:

```
public static void UpdateDebrief(int ID, string ItemNo, int QtyDelivered, int QtyNOTDelivered, string Reason)
{
    if (Session["Debrief"] == null)
    {
        JobDebrief deb = new JobDebrief
        {
            JobID = ID,
            ItemNo = "",
            QtyDelivered = 0,
            QtyNotDelivered = 0,
            DbriefReason = "",
            DbriefDate = DateTime.Now,
            DbriefedBy = CurrentUser.UserID
        };
        Session["Debrief"] = deb;
        deb.Create();
    }
}
```

You may want to set this session variable on your page load with something like

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
        Session("Debrief") = ReadDebriefFromDB();
        ....
    }
}
```

***Important***

But if this "debrief" thing is a one per "Item" or "Job", you would have to add a field to each of those objects that holds your debrief object.  That probably means having a hidden column in your grid that holds a pointer to this debrief object, then you can test on the value of that column being null or not.

Comment: And what happens if the user logs out, logs back in to edit the debrief?

Comment: @shf301 - you are entirely correct, this "debrief" thing he is talking is certainly something that is persistent (he is saving it to the database), and might be on a per "job" or per "item" basis.  He really needs to have a property on the job or item, or wherever appropriate that points to that debrief, and that is initialized to null.  He could then check to see if it is null or not.

Comment: What do I need to create a Session? I get the error: `Error 2436 Method must have a return type`

Comment: Sorry that should be brackets instead of parenthesis.  I have made the edit to my answer.

Comment: But in view of @shf301 comment, i think a better answer is to have a hidden column in your grid, if this debrief thing is on a per line basis.  This column would be read from the db like the others, and contain a pointer to the debrief object which you can use to test on (null = debrief not created).

Comment: I made significant edits to my answer (thanks @shf301).  Please review.

Answer (score 2):

You appear to already know that you are in an update case since you are calling `UpdateDebrief`.  So why is `UpdateDebrief` creating a new `Debrief` and calling the `Create()` method?

Instead `UpdateDebrief` should load the existing `Debrief` record from the database and update it.  It's not clear what you are using for your database layer so I can't give you a more specific answer.

Comment: The update needs to be created first when something gets updated. But I don't want a new one being created each time so that is why I need to check if has already been created then don't run again

Comment: You can always query the database to see if the `Debrief` record already exists.